# How to get Blender 2.79 to work on Ubuntu 22.04.1?

Tags: 22.04, blender, segmentation-fault

I recently upgraded from 20.04.4 to 22.04.1.  Despite some initial hiccups, so far it works great.  HOWEVER, I am running into an issue with Blender.  My system's hardware will not work for any version of Blender beyond 2.79.  I have installed it via tar from Blender's website.  Whenever I use it, it crashes when I select an object.  The same thing happens when I try running Blender after downloading from Software Center.  I can load a file, and when I right-click to select an object, it crashes.
The terminal says "segmentation fault," so something is not working right.

As I stated, due to my system's limitations (yes, it's old), I am unable to run anything past Blender 2.79. I would like to know if it's something I can fix with my current setup.

After a little bit of runaround, I heard from the devs at Blender.  2.79 is not being supported (big shock). To add to my question, if it is allowed, if it's no longer supported, then why is it being offered, both from their website and as a snap in the software center?

For those interested, this is the output of my blender.crash.txt.  For context, this is version 2.79b from snap, downloaded from the Software Center:

```
# Blender 2.79 (sub 0), Commit date: 2018-03-22 14:10, Hash f4dc9f9d68b
```

## backtrace

/snap/blender/20/./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x20) [0x1a6c700]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x1078395]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x42520) [0x7fc2a5368520]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-14.so.1(_ZN4llvm11BitCastInstC2EPNS_5ValueEPNS_4TypeERKNS_5TwineEPNS_11InstructionE+0x6f) [0x7fc287e18e4f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-14.so.1(*ZN4llvm8CastInst6CreateENS_11Instruction7CastOpsEPNS_5ValueEPNS_4TypeERKNS_5TwineEPS1*+0x221) [0x7fc287e16bc1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-14.so.1(+0xe9bef2) [0x7fc287d3fef2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-14.so.1(LLVMBuildBitCast+0x43) [0x7fc287d82f13]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x665d37) [0x7fc28ddfcd37]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x114e38b) [0x7fc28e8e538b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x66a041) [0x7fc28de01041]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x63a751) [0x7fc28ddd1751]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x5db14c) [0x7fc28dd7214c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x5ef37b) [0x7fc28dd8637b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x57313b) [0x7fc28dd0a13b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x11535fc) [0x7fc28e8ea5fc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x585e4c) [0x7fc28dd1ce4c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x590213) [0x7fc28dd27213]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x36388d) [0x7fc28dafa88d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x298a95) [0x7fc28da2fa95]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x298c02) [0x7fc28da2fc02]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/crocus_dri.so(+0x2a0f0f) [0x7fc28da37f0f]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x176b7d4]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x1178069]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(draw_object+0x1b93) [0x1185d93]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(draw_object_select+0x31) [0x1187fb1]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(ED_view3d_draw_select_loop+0x1c9) [0x1152199]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(view3d_opengl_select+0x18e) [0x11719de]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x11682b0]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x116b285]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x116ba35]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x107fb09]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x1080f21]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x10815f8]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x1081958]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x507) [0x1081f97]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(WM_main+0x18) [0x1078f78]
/snap/blender/20/./blender(main+0x3f8) [0x1016a38]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7fc2a534fd90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7fc2a534fe40]
/snap/blender/20/./blender() [0x10752ee]

Comment: It's possible that a segmentation fault is caused by a bug in their code or a bug in how their code uses a library that has been changed in 22.04.  Or, it could be the library itself has a bug.  In either case, you might want to let the developers of Blender know.  Perhaps it will help them troubleshoot your problem.  If they are able to tell you which library (if it is a library) is the cause, then while they fix that problem, you might be able to install an older version of that library.  But I think figuring out the cause without their help would be difficult.

Comment: And they probably won't care about an old version.

Comment: Did you try the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/blender)? Version 2.79 is still available as a snap. Because this version is so old, it may not be supported by its dependencies in Ubuntu repositories, especially in 22.04 which is newer by four years since the time blender 2.79 was released. Snaps are packaged with all their dependencies so you can circumvent using the dependencies in your release.

Comment: The snap version crashes.  The downloads from the Blender website crashes. It's odd that it would do this, if the dependencies come with it.

Comment: Further details; it does not crash as long as I don't right-click to select a mesh. Selecting the camera does nothing.  Selecting the lamp does nothing. Selecting a mesh?  Crashes.  Just to make sure it wasn't my file, I tried it with the default cube, a plane, icosphere, etc.  I can select items from the menu and it doesn't crash.  I ended up downloading the snap version (2.79b) and have been going very carefully with it.  There was a recommended fix, I think about having to add a line to ./profile, but I didn't know how to go about it, and wasn't sure it would fix the problem.

Comment: I actually just assumed you were only using the 2D or animation features in blender. If your hardware can just barely run the application by itself, I find it a bit unrealistic to expect that you will be able to use the 3D modeling and animation features without frequent crashes or crawling performance. You should reevaluate your expectations from this hardware so it is realistic.

Comment: My specs meet the  requirements for 2.79, and I use it mainly to make a model and render. It worked fine when I had 20.04. The only change is the upgrade.

Comment: Nmath, please try to include information that is actually useful to addressing the issue. I use Blender for rendering, not animation. I am able to use the node editor, right-clicking on cycles doesn't make it crash.  It seems to be a problem in the main window.  When I contacted the devs at Blender, their response was equally not helpful towards resolving the problem.  Instead of bashing my request as unrealistic, please either kill the editorial, or provide information that is actually useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Segmentation faults are a cryptic way of saying, illegal memory access attempted. It's a code related thing. There really is no way for a user to track it down much less fix it. You can report a bug in blender [here](https://www.blender.org/support/)

Comment: I flagged as useful because it actually pointed me in a direction that ultimately led to the answer.  Thank you, Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I *think* I found the answer here:

https://developer.blender.org/T52527

At the bottom, there is a recommendation of going into User Preferences, and changing the Selection method to "Changing to Occlusion Queries".  That seemed to have done the trick...no more crashing when I right-click to select an object in the main window!